# Looping between OpenForms excluding the ActiveMdiChild

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a loop which runs for every form excluding the activeform... I found a solution which I could use `ActiveForm.ActiveMdiChild.Name = FormRefresh.Name` but the problem is if I've 2 forms of same name, It'll not loop in the not active form...

```
Public Shared Sub VerificaAlterações()
    For Each FormRefresh As Form In Application.OpenForms()
                If ActiveForm.ActiveMdiChild = FormRefresh Then Continue For ' Error here
                ' Do some work...
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Edit: **The problem was the `Shared` in Sub... I removed it and it worked with the answer below.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to compare the names of the forms when you can compare the forms themselves:

```vb
If FormRefresh Is ActiveMdiChild Then Continue For
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error with that code...

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression Status
Error BC30369 Cannot reference a possible instance member of a class from within a shared method or a shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class

Comment: @HeitorBadotti, given that you don't mention any error in the question, saying that you get the same error seems to suggest that you left critical information out of the question. That said, I see that I used just `ActiveMdiChild` rather than `ActiveForm.ActiveMdiChild`, but you could have just changed that yourself. I'm not really sure why this code would be in a `Shared` method in the first place but I get the feeling that the larger code is suboptimal in many ways and we probably can't fix all of them in one go.

Comment: Yes, the code is in a Shared... I didn't mention that, and I see now the problem is that... I didn't know when it's in Shared it doesn't works. I edited the question. Thanks a lot for the helping.